# Sort words in every line

Tags: python, sorting

I have a line with words such as

```
ΜΔΣ,ΘΟΡ,ΑΛΒ
```

and a python script that sorts the words alphabetically

```
items = input("Input comma separated sequence of words")
words = [word for word in items.split(",")]
print(",".join(sorted(list(set(words)))))
```

which outputs the correct answer

```
ΑΛΒ,ΘΟΡ,ΜΔΣ
```

I would like to enter a multiple line input such as

```
ΜΔΣ,ΘΟΡ,ΑΛΒ
ΜΔΣ,ΣΥΝ,ΑΛΒ
```

and get

```
ΑΛΒ,ΘΟΡ,ΜΔΣ
ΑΛΒ,ΜΔΣ,ΣΥΝ
```

What changes I have to do in my code? Thanks.

Comment: So you are asking us to do your work for you? What data structures or algorithms have you considered? Did you try anything at all? Where are you stuck in the code? Provide us something to tangible to help with

Comment: The question could be better if there was an attempt to solve the multiple-line-problem, but I don't think it's *that* bad that closure is warranted considering OP already solved the problem for a single input-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function, map it onto a list of your lines.

```
>>> def sort_unique_words(words): 
...:     return ','.join(sorted(set(words.split(',')))) 
...:                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> line = 'ΜΔΣ,ΘΟΡ,ΑΛΒ'                                                                                                                                                     
>>> sort_unique_words(line)                                                                                                                                                  
'ΑΛΒ,ΘΟΡ,ΜΔΣ'
>>>                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> lines = '''ΜΔΣ,ΘΟΡ,ΑΛΒ 
...: ΜΔΣ,ΣΥΝ,ΑΛΒ'''                                                                                                                                                          
>>>                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> '\n'.join(map(sort_unique_words, lines.splitlines()))                                                                                                                    
'ΑΛΒ,ΘΟΡ,ΜΔΣ\nΑΛΒ,ΜΔΣ,ΣΥΝ'
>>> print(_)                                                                                                                                                                 
ΑΛΒ,ΘΟΡ,ΜΔΣ
ΑΛΒ,ΜΔΣ,ΣΥΝ
```

My function is very similar to what you already did, note that

```
[word for word in items.split(",")]
```

is the same as

```
items.split(",")
```

If you want to include duplicates in the result, get rid of the `set` constructor.